# "TypeError: t.start is undefined", in fullcalendar.min.js while using on my website for google calender functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am getting below error while using fullcalender on my website...

**"TypeError: t.start is undefined"**, in fullcalendar.min.js while using on my website for google calender functionality

```
TypeError: t.start is undefined    
... == t.allDay && (t.allDay = !(t.start.hasTime() || t.end && t.end.hasTime())), t...      
fullcal....min.js (line 713, col 44)
```

My fullcalender JS code is

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next,today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyA6Cw8V_MPSGbqZTa66CW0yVCkuG8lE2Uo',
            events: [
                {
                    googleCalendarId: 'ashish.raj189@gmail.com'
                },
            ],
        });
    });
```

Could you tell me what should do for fix the **TypeError**?

I am using gcal.html library file of fullcalendar-2.3.1, downloaded from http://fullcalendar.io/download/

I have included moment.min.js, jquery.min.js, fullcalendar.min.js, gcal.js

In my website header I have used some other js libraries also... but how to resolve the issue if this coming because of any other library... please help me friends...

Comment: adding question and better format

Comment: Could you post your html? what libraries are you including? and where's that JS code located at?

Comment: thanks -Skatok for your formatting and helping to explain question better...
i have edited the post and explained a bit more and guess the reasoin for the error... please see if you can help me to resolve the issue...

Comment: I would need some html o any place where you could put the website, seems like a dependency is not being resolved.

Comment: i have already given all dependent js library in my website page for use the fullcalender... but still it gives error ... dont know why... :(

Comment: I have created an js fiddle for you and it works great https://jsfiddle.net/nkowsatb/3/

Comment: thanks Franky... the js code which you used in the above jsfiddle link is working really fine for me also... thanks alot...
just do me a favor by vote up my question ...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for others. Wrap your code in

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // Your Code
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, except that I use the database to import the information. Indeed the problem in my case come from format of dates, and I was able to correct that using these methods:

- **Date_create ()**: to create the date from the field of the database
  example: `$start = date_create($row->start_date)`
- **Date_format()**: to convert the date to a datetime 
  example: `date_format ($start, 'Y-m-d H:i:s')`

I hope it'll help to solve your problem

Comment: I have this error called 'a.start is undefined' and it comes only in Mozilla Firefox. What could be the cause of it..?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was retrieving the events from server using ajax.The unexpected response recieved, when passed to callback causes the issue. The response needs to be properly handled and the callback should be called only if the response is of appropriate format.